# returning undefined when no items in array after reduce method javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array as such:

```js
let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Chromebook 2",
    type: "computer",
    price: 399.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Programming 101",
    type: "book", 
    price: 15.00
  }
]
```

I need to create a function that loops through the array and finds the most expensive item and returns the itemName. and if  if there are no items in the array passed in, my mostExpensiveItemName should return undefined I have a reduce function that returns the most expensive item but i cannot get it to return undefined when given an itemless array

```
function mostExpensiveItemName(items){
  var maxItem = items.reduce((max,min) => max.price > min.price ? max : min)
  return maxItem.itemName
}
```

thats the function i have so far the only missing piece is having it return undefined when there are no items in the array passed in

Comment: `if (items.length === 0) return;`, there may be alternatives, but this seems to be among the easier and also well-readable ways.

Comment: i was doing that after and it wasnt working is there a specific reason that has to come before the reduce part? or does it have to come after?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is probably an `if`:

```
function mostExpensiveItemName(items){
    if (!items.length) {
        return; // Or `return undefined;` if you want to emphasize the return value
    }
    const maxItem = items.reduce((max, min) => max.price > min.price ? max : min);
    return maxItem.itemName;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function mostExpensiveItemName(items){
    if (!items.length) {
        return; // Or `return undefined;` if you want to emphasize the return value
    }
    const maxItem = items.reduce((max, min) => max.price > min.price ? max : min);
    return maxItem.itemName;
}

console.log(mostExpensiveItemName([]));

let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Chromebook 2",
    type: "computer",
    price: 399.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Programming 101",
    type: "book", 
    price: 15.00
  }
];

console.log(mostExpensiveItemName(items));
```

Alternatively, you could seed the `reduce` with `{itemName: undefined}` or, somewhat more robustly, `{itemName: undefined, price: -Infinity}`:

```
function mostExpensiveItemName(items){
    const maxItem = items.reduce(
        (max, min) => max.price > min.price ? max : min,
        {itemName: undefined, price: -Infinity} // ***
    );
    return maxItem.itemName;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function mostExpensiveItemName(items){
    const maxItem = items.reduce(
        (max, min) => max.price > min.price ? max : min,
        {itemName: undefined, price: -Infinity} // ***
    );
    return maxItem.itemName;
}

console.log(mostExpensiveItemName([]));

let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Chromebook 2",
    type: "computer",
    price: 399.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Programming 101",
    type: "book", 
    price: 15.00
  }
];

console.log(mostExpensiveItemName(items));
```

(The version without `price: -Infinity` relies on the fact that `max.price > min.price` will be false if there are any entries in the array with a valid `price`, since `undefined > number` is converted to `NaN > number` which is always false.)

Comment: This is what was tripping me up. i get a type error about the initial value and wasnt sure how to set it the pric: - infinity was som ething i stumbled across but i was extremely unclear as to how to implement it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Is it not an option to do:

```
if(!items.length) return undefined;
```

before the reduce?

Comment: Answers should be answers, not questions. (Not least because asking it as a question reads as sarcasm.)

Comment: i hadnt considered that lol im new tbh so my logic was tghat i would have to do something like this after the reduce

Answer (score 0):

Reduce lets you give an initial value so initialize it with an empty object so that its `itemName` is `undefined` as desired

```js
function mostExpensiveItemName(items){
  var maxItem = items.reduce(
    (max,min) => max.price > min.price ? max : min,
    {}  // initialize with an empty object so its itemName is undefined
  );
  return maxItem.itemName;
}

const items = [ { itemName: 'one', price: 5 }, { itemName: 'two', price: 8 }];

var result = mostExpensiveItemName([]);
console.log('when array is empty:', result);
result = mostExpensiveItemName(items);
console.log('when array has data:', result);
```

Comment: im not sure what you mean by initialise unless you mean prior to reduce setting an if statement. although that doesnt look like what you mean at all.

Comment: nevermind i see now what you mean {itemName:undefined,price:- infinity}

Comment: Initializing to an empty object as shown above (the line with the comment) is enough. no need to set an infinite price since there are no other objects to compare with